# Sending an email to a Gmail account in vue 3 using email-js version 3.2.0

Tags: email, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, email-validation, email-client

I am trying to send  an email to my Gmail account using email-js latest version in vue 3 composition API but whenever I try to do so I get an error in the console stating that net:err timed out although I configured everything correctly and I am having an internet connection . Below is the code I am using :

```
      <q-dialog class="gt-sm"  v-model="dialog">
        <div align="center">
        <q-card  class="my-card" align="center">
            <q-card style="padding-top:20px;" align="center">
            <p>Place Reservation Order</p>
        <q-form method="post" @submit.prevent="Submit" style="max-width:280px;" align="center">
            <q-input label="Name" id="name" v-model="name">
                <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <q-icon name="person"/>
                </template>
            </q-input>

               <q-input label="Phone number" id="phone" v-model="phone">
                <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <q-icon name="call"/>
                </template>
            </q-input>

               <q-input label="Table number" id="table" v-model="table">
                <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <q-icon name="table"/>
                </template>
            </q-input>

               <q-input label="Food" id="food" v-model="food">
                <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <q-icon name="money"/>
                </template>
            </q-input>

            <q-btn flat color="blue" type="submit" label="Send"></q-btn>

        </q-form>
            </q-card>
        </q-card>
        </div>
      </q-dialog>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue' 
import TastyHeader from '../components/TastyHeader.vue'
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com'
export default {
    components:{
        TastyHeader
    },
    setup(){
        const name =ref('')
        const food = ref('')
        const table =ref('')
        const phone = ref('')

        const Submit=()=>{
              var param = {
                table: table.value,
        phone: phone.value,
        food: food.value,
        name: name.value
              }
        emailjs
        .send('service_disx46e', 'template_3y41wc8',param,'user_1Y8lbGgVXBoY0P8yd')
        .then(
                    (result) => {
                        console.log('SUCCESS!', result.status, result.text)
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log('FAILED...', error)
                    }
                )
      const newTodo = {
        // id:uuidv4(),
        table: table.value,
        phone: phone.value,
        food: food.value,
        name: name.value
      }
       console.log('newTodo:', newTodo)
        }
return{
            Submit,
            table,
            phone,
            food,
           name,
           dialog:ref(false)
        }
    }
```

Sending an email to Gmail account but I am not able to

Comment: Can you share the complete error message that you get?

Comment: POST https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
eval @ sendPost.js?be61:22
sendPost @ sendPost.js?be61:4
eval @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?0f3e:1482
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?21f2:155
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?21f2:164
eval @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.j
eval @ QForm.js?3cb4:120
Promise.then (async)
submit @ QForm.js?3cb4:116
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?21f2:155
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?21f2:164
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?0f3e:370

Comment: I removed some of errors since it is too long by 104 characters

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. You setup everything according to documentation. But I see that you're importing from "emailjs-com" which is deprecated. Does it work with "@emailjs/browser" import?

Comment: Still I encounter the same error even after I run npm install @emailjs/browser

Comment: Can you create a new template and new service and test with those? If it is still not working, try using the library with vanilla js in a new project.

Comment: I successfully solved seems the proxy settings in the network were wrong and also the public key should not contain 'user_'. Now I only got one problem clearing the form after submitting it